# wrong argument unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

good day every one im just wonder what seems to be my problem i dont think im have any problem with my code im having problem with a **wrong number of arguments** error in my test_image_url test

```
==============================================================================
SUITE test,test/unit/helpers,test/unit,test/performance,test/functional (SEED 49459)
==============================================================================
ActionController::TestCase
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
ActionView::TestCase
ActiveRecord::TestCase
ActiveSupport::TestCase
ProductTest
     test_image_url                                           0:00:00:163 ERROR
        wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
        Exception `ArgumentError' at:
        /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `block in run'
        /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:408:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
        /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'
     test_product_attributes_must_not_be_empty                0:00:00:317 PASS
     test_product_must_be_postive_price                       0:00:00:326 PASS
ProductsHelperTest
==============================================================================
  pass: 2,  fail: 0,  error: 1
  total: 3 tests with 10 assertions in 0.3286295 seconds
==============================================================================
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/...]

Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my unit test:

```
     require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def new_product
      product = Product.new(:title => "MyBook",
                          :description => "Famouse myBook",
                          :image_url => "zz.jpg")

  end

  test "product attributes must not be empty" do
      product = Product.new
      assert product.invalid?
      assert product.errors[:title].any?
      assert product.errors[:description].any?
      assert product.errors[:price].any?
      assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end

   test "product must be postive price" do
        product = Product.new(:title => "MyBook",
                          :description => "Famouse myBook",
                          :image_url => "zz.jpg")

        product.price = -1
        assert product.invalid?
        assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
        product.errors[:price].join('; ')

        product.price = 0
        assert product.invalid?
        assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
        product.errors[:price].join('; ')

        product.price = 1
        assert product.valid?
  end 


  test "image url" do
       ok = %w{fred.gif fred.jpg fred.png FRED.JPG FRED.PNG FRED.GIF
                     http://a.b.c/x/y/z/fred.gif}
            bad = %w{fred.doc fred.gif/more fred.gif.more}    

            ok.each do |name|
              assert new_product(name).valid?, "#{name} shoudn't be invalid"
            end


            bad.each do |b|
             assert new_product(name).invalid?, "#{name} shoudn't be valid"
            end
       end








end
```

EDIT: sovled
thanks for the help i figured out whats wrong

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def new_product(image_url)
      product = Product.new(:title => "MyBook",
                          :description => "Famouse myBook",
                          :price => 1 ,
                          :image_url => image_url)

  end

  test "product attributes must not be empty" do
      product = Product.new
      assert product.invalid?
      assert product.errors[:title].any?
      assert product.errors[:description].any?
      assert product.errors[:price].any?
      assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end

   test "product must be postive price" do
        product = Product.new(:title => "MyBook",
                          :description => "Famouse myBook",
                          :image_url => "zz.jpg")

        product.price = -1
        assert product.invalid?
        assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
        product.errors[:price].join('; ')

        product.price = 0
        assert product.invalid?
        assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
        product.errors[:price].join('; ')

        product.price = 1
        assert product.valid?
  end 


  test "image url" do
       ok = %w{fred.gif fred.jpg fred.png FRED.JPG FRED.PNG FRED.GIF
                     http://a.b.c/x/y/z/fred.gif}
           # bad = %w{fred.doc fred.gif/more fred.gif.more}    
            bad = %w{ fred.doc fred.gif/more fred.gif.more }

        ok.each do |name|
        assert new_product(name).valid?, "#{name} shouldn't be invalid"
        end
        bad.each do |name|
        assert new_product(name).invalid?, "#{name} shouldn't be valid"
        end

=begin
            ok.each do |name|
              assert new_product(name).valid?, "#{name} shoudn't be invalid"
            end
            bad.each do |name|
             assert new_product(name).invalid?, "#{name} shoudn't be valid"
            end
=end

       end
end
```

um running in rails 3.1 
ruby 1.9

thanks more power to us

Comment: Can you post your passing tests as well, or the whole test file?

Comment: @bdon file already posted thank you for your concern

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure your issue. Because your not using the any `setup,teardown` methods in the above code. Provide full test case or just check the methods `setup` and `teardown` have any arguments operation. The issue related to that only.